# Uniform Boundedness Principle for $L^p( \mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^p$ such that for each $g\in
>  L^q$, the sequence $\{\int f_n g\}$ is bounded. Then $\{f_n\}$ is
> bounded in $L^p$. $(1\leq p<\infty)$

**Proof:** Argue by contradiction, suppose there exists a subsequence such that
$$||f_{n_k}||_p \geq k.$$

Then we define a sequence $g_k \in L^q$ (this is the conjugate function from Royden's book),
$$g_k = ||f_{n_k}||_p^{1-p} \operatorname{sgn}(f(x)) |f(x)|^{p-1},$$
we have that $||g_k||_q = 1$ and $\int f_{n_k} g_k = ||f_{n_k}||_p \geq k$ which contradicts the assumption.

Is this okay? thank you very much!

Comment: No. You would need to find a *single* $g$ such that $\bigl(\int f_{n_k}g\bigr) $ is unbounded.  You might find it easier to prove your assertion directly, using the theorem named in your title.

Comment: Suppose the sequence $|\int f_n g|$ is bounded by $M$, can I choose a $k\geq M$ to get that $\int f_{n_k} g_k \geq k \geq M$?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this is easier to prove if you use the uniform boundedness principle. I will assume you meant that $\frac1q+\frac1p=1$.

Now, since $(L^q(\mathbb{R}))'$ is isometric to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, we can interpret the sequence $(f_n)$ as a sequence of functionals in $(L^q(\mathbb{R}))'$. Then the condition says that for each $g\in L^q(\mathbb{R})$, we have that $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |f_n(g)|<\infty$. Since $L^q(\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space, the uniform boundedness principle implies $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\|f_n\|<\infty$.